# Capistrano deploy fail because of mimemagic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capistrano

Im currently learning ruby rails deployment with capistrano.

I'm trying to deploy on my server an ruby on rails app with capistrano. The app use postgres. the server is a vps on debian. I'm using ruby 2.7.2

When i run `bundle exec cap production deploy`

its work fine until the bundle install step, then i get:

```
** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


  INFO [b0d8548e] Finished in 5.718 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [5b5f514a] Running if test ! -d /home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325230506; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325230506'" 1>&2; false; fi as root@my-website.org

 DEBUG [5b5f514a] Command: if test ! -d /home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325230506; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325230506'" 1>&2; false; fi

 DEBUG [5b5f514a] Finished in 0.223 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [0988c64c] Running /home/roger/my-website.org/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle check as root@my-website.org

 DEBUG [0988c64c] Command: cd /home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325230506 && /home/roger/my-website.org/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle check

 DEBUG [0988c64c]       Your Gemfile lists the gem hashie-forbidden_attributes (>= 0) more than once.

You should probably keep only one of them.

Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.

While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.

 DEBUG [0988c64c]       https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources.git (at master@80bbdc3) is

not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.

 DEBUG [0988c64c] Finished in 6.042 seconds with exit status 11 (failed).

  INFO [a5e6399b] Running /home/roger/my-website.org/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --jobs 4 --quiet as root@my-website.org

 DEBUG [a5e6399b] Command: cd /home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325230506 && /home/roger/my-website.org/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --jobs 4 --quiet

 DEBUG [a5e6399b]       Your bundle is locked to mimemagic (0.3.6), but that version could not be found

in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources,

that means the author of mimemagic (0.3.6) has removed it. You'll need to update

your bundle to a version other than mimemagic (0.3.6) that hasn't been removed

in order to install
```

Its look like this version of mimemagic is no longer available.
So i moved the mimemagic version number directly in the gemfile.
(Its not very cool, but im not using directly mimemagic, and i hope maybe the gem that use the uncorrect version of mimemagic could be soon updated)
i just get another error:

```
** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


 DEBUG [b5296d44] Command: cd /home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325231138 && /home/roger/my-website.org/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle config --local without development:test

  INFO [b5296d44] Finished in 6.180 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [2112f82b] Running if test ! -d /home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325231138; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325231138'" 1>&2; false; fi as root@my-website.org

 DEBUG [2112f82b] Command: if test ! -d /home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325231138; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325231138'" 1>&2; false; fi

 DEBUG [2112f82b] Finished in 0.230 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

 DEBUG [011e44ad] Running /home/roger/my-website.org/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle check as root@my-website.org

 DEBUG [011e44ad] Command: cd /home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325231138 && /home/roger/my-website.org/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle check

 DEBUG [011e44ad]       Your Gemfile lists the gem hashie-forbidden_attributes (>= 0) more than once.

You should probably keep only one of them.

Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.

While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.

 DEBUG [011e44ad]       https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources.git (at master@80bbdc3) is

not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.

 DEBUG [011e44ad] Finished in 6.064 seconds with exit status 11 (failed).

  INFO [539a9888] Running /home/roger/my-website.org/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --jobs 4 --quiet as root@my-website.org

 DEBUG [539a9888] Command: cd /home/roger/my-website.org/releases/20210325231138 && /home/roger/my-website.org/rvm1scripts/rvm-auto.sh . /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle install --jobs 4 --quiet

 DEBUG [539a9888]       Downloading mimemagic-0.4.2 revealed dependencies not in the API or the lockfile

(nokogiri (~> 1), rake (>= 0)).

Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update mimemagic`

should fix the problem.
```

It suggest me to run `bundle update mimemagic` fo solve the problém.
But i know how to run it in local, i know how to run on my server... but in dont know how to run specificaly during the capistrano deploy process.

Somebody have an idea about something i could try for solve this issue?
Thanks

edit: i tried to move in the gemlock to mimemagic 0.3.9 and i get this error message when running `bundle exec cap production deploy`

```
An error occurred while installing mimemagic (0.3.9), and Bundler cannot

continue.

Make sure that `gem install mimemagic -v '0.3.9' --source

'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.



In Gemfile:

  grape_on_rails_routes was resolved to 0.3.2, which depends on

    rails was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on

      actionmailbox was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on

        activestorage was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on

          marcel was resolved to 0.3.3, which depends on

            mimemagic
```

ps: my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.7.2'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'devise'
gem 'ed25519'
gem 'bcrypt_pbkdf'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '6.0.0'
gem 'redis'
gem 'grape'
gem 'gon'
gem 'cookies_eu'
gem 'grape-entity'
gem 'grape_on_rails_routes'
gem 'hashie-forbidden_attributes'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.6.1'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'kaminari'   #gem qui permet de gerer un affichage sur plusieurs pages d'une liste
gem 'cloudinary', '~> 1.9.1' #pour uploader et retoucher simplement des photos
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2' # c'est la gem qui associe une photo ou un fichier uploadé a un modéle
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin/activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'stripe_event'
gem 'hashie-forbidden_attributes'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano3-puma', github: "seuros/capistrano-puma"
  gem 'rvm1-capistrano3', require: false


end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'

end
```

my gemlock:

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git
  revision: d1296678b9efdfd31cf56b98a0c8e7d7a3260ad5
  specs:
    activeadmin (2.9.0)
      arbre (~> 1.2, >= 1.2.1)
      formtastic (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      formtastic_i18n (~> 0.4)
      inherited_resources (~> 1.7)
      jquery-rails (~> 4.2)
      kaminari (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.1)
      railties (>= 5.2, < 6.2)
      ransack (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources.git
  revision: 80bbdc309ad5cf69c84710f27df485b212a21d4a
  specs:
    inherited_resources (1.12.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2, < 6.2)
      has_scope (~> 0.6)
      railties (>= 5.2, < 6.2)
      responders (>= 2, < 4)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma.git
  revision: 186826736ac83c550fd6129728284584b8c9c782
  specs:
    capistrano3-puma (5.0.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.7)
      capistrano-bundler
      puma (>= 4.0, < 6.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      activestorage (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      actionview (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.0)
      actionview (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      activestorage (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
    activerecord (6.0.0)
      activemodel (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
    activestorage (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (6.0.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.8)
    airbrussh (1.4.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.6.1, != 1.7.0)
    arbre (1.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 6.2)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.2, < 1.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (10.2.4.0)
      execjs
    aws_cf_signer (0.1.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.16)
    bcrypt_pbkdf (1.1.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.7.3)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capistrano (3.16.0)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (2.0.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
    capistrano-rails (1.6.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (>= 1.1, < 3)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    carrierwave (1.3.2)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      ssrf_filter (~> 1.0)
    cloudinary (1.9.1)
      aws_cf_signer
      rest-client
    coderay (1.1.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.8)
    cookies_eu (1.7.7)
      js_cookie_rails (~> 2.2.0)
    crass (1.0.6)
    devise (4.7.3)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.4.4)
    domain_name (0.5.20190701)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    dotenv (2.7.6)
    dotenv-rails (2.7.6)
      dotenv (= 2.7.6)
      railties (>= 3.2)
    dry-configurable (0.12.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      dry-core (~> 0.5, >= 0.5.0)
    dry-container (0.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      dry-configurable (~> 0.1, >= 0.1.3)
    dry-core (0.5.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    dry-inflector (0.2.0)
    dry-logic (1.1.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      dry-core (~> 0.5, >= 0.5)
    dry-types (1.5.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      dry-container (~> 0.3)
      dry-core (~> 0.5, >= 0.5)
      dry-inflector (~> 0.1, >= 0.1.2)
      dry-logic (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    ed25519 (1.2.4)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.15.0)
    font-awesome-sass (5.6.1)
      sassc (>= 1.11)
    formtastic (4.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2.0)
    formtastic_i18n (0.6.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    gon (6.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.20)
      i18n (>= 0.7)
      multi_json
      request_store (>= 1.0)
    grape (1.5.3)
      activesupport
      builder
      dry-types (>= 1.1)
      mustermann-grape (~> 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.3.0)
      rack-accept
    grape-entity (0.9.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.3.2)
    grape_on_rails_routes (0.3.2)
      rails (>= 3.1.1)
    has_scope (0.8.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
    hashie (4.1.0)
    hashie-forbidden_attributes (0.1.1)
      hashie (>= 3.0)
    http-accept (1.7.0)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    i18n (1.8.9)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.4.0)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    js_cookie_rails (2.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    kaminari (1.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.2.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.2.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.2.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.2.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.1)
    kaminari-core (1.2.1)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    loofah (2.9.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (= 0.3.9)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mime-types (3.3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2021.0225)
    mimemagic (0.3.9)
      nokogiri (~> 1)
      rake
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.5.0)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    monetize (1.9.4)
      money (~> 6.12)
    money (6.13.8)
      i18n (>= 0.6.4, <= 2)
    money-rails (1.14.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      monetize (~> 1.9.0)
      money (~> 6.13.2)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    msgpack (1.4.2)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    mustermann (1.1.1)
      ruby2_keywords (~> 0.0.1)
    mustermann-grape (1.0.1)
      mustermann (>= 1.0.0)
    net-scp (3.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5, < 7.0.0)
    net-ssh (6.1.0)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nio4r (2.5.7)
    nokogiri (1.11.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.5.0)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.21.0)
    pry (0.13.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    pry-byebug (3.9.0)
      byebug (~> 11.0)
      pry (~> 0.13.0)
    pry-rails (0.3.9)
      pry (>= 0.10.4)
    puma (5.2.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.5.2)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-accept (0.4.5)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.0)
      actioncable (= 6.0.0)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.0)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      actiontext (= 6.0.0)
      actionview (= 6.0.0)
      activejob (= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (= 6.0.0)
      activerecord (= 6.0.0)
      activestorage (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.0.0)
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)
      activesupport (= 6.0.0)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.3)
    ransack (2.4.2)
      activerecord (>= 5.2.4)
      activesupport (>= 5.2.4)
      i18n
    rb-fsevent (0.10.4)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    redis (4.2.5)
    request_store (1.5.0)
      rack (>= 1.4)
    responders (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    rest-client (2.1.0)
      http-accept (>= 1.7.0, < 2.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    rspec-core (3.10.1)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.10.1)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.10.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10.0)
    rspec-rails (4.0.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      railties (>= 4.2)
      rspec-core (~> 3.10)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.10)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.10)
      rspec-support (~> 3.10)
    rspec-support (3.10.2)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.4)
    rvm1-capistrano3 (1.4.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.2)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    semantic_range (3.0.0)
    simple_form (5.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activemodel (>= 5.2)
    spring (2.1.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sshkit (1.21.2)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    ssrf_filter (1.0.7)
    stripe (5.30.0)
    stripe_event (2.3.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1)
      stripe (>= 2.8, < 6)
    thor (1.1.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    tzinfo (1.2.9)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.7)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (4.1.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webpacker (5.2.1)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.3)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin!
  autoprefixer-rails
  bcrypt_pbkdf
  bootsnap
  capistrano
  capistrano-bundler
  capistrano-rails
  capistrano-rvm
  capistrano3-puma!
  carrierwave (~> 1.2)
  cloudinary (~> 1.9.1)
  cookies_eu
  devise
  dotenv-rails
  ed25519
  font-awesome-sass (~> 5.6.1)
  gon
  grape
  grape-entity
  grape_on_rails_routes
  hashie-forbidden_attributes
  inherited_resources!
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  kaminari
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  money-rails
  pg (~> 0.21)
  pry-byebug
  pry-rails
  puma
  rails (= 6.0.0)
  redis
  rspec-rails (~> 4.0.2)
  rvm1-capistrano3
  sassc-rails
  simple_form
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  stripe
  stripe_event
  uglifier
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webpacker

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.7.2p137

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

Comment: Run `bundle update mimemagic` locally, your `Gemfile.lock` should change. Commit and push those changes and then deploy again.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried but i get that "Bundler attempted to update mimemagic but its version stayed the same"

Comment: i don know wich gem of my gemfile is calling the mimemagic gem , because as you can see in my gemfile, i didnt put mimemagic myself. Maybe if i could identify wich of "my" gem is calling mimemagic, i could update this gem and it would fix the issue

Comment: Read your Gemfile.lock to see the gem dependencies. There you should find which gem is using mimemagic.

Comment: You should probably use mimemagic 0.3.9. Also remove the duplicate entry of hashie-forbidden_attributes you have in your Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks for answer. in the gemlock its not very clear, mimemagic appear 2 times, one under marcel and one under nothing.  I tried to move to mimemagic 0.3.9 in the gemlock as you proposed and i get another error message that give me some informations: its too long, i will update the topic.

Comment: Do you think the last part of error message mean that its grape_on_rails_routes the cause of all of this mess?

Answer (score 5):

i salved the issue by using `apt install shared-mime-info`

on mac its `brew install shared-mime-info`

and then `bundle update nokogiri marcel mimemagic`

After using that on my server and on my developping computer and moving a bit the mimemagic versions its worked.

Im not running in another issue. thanks for your help :-)